# Notebook drivers for NVIDIA card

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I was looking for NVIDIA drivers that would enable me to do some CUDA programming. Ordinary drivers don't seem to work for me - right now I'm on Windows 7 with NVIDIA netbook drivers 185.85. I was looking at Ubuntu section and it seems to be lacking notebook version. I tried using normal drivers on Ubuntu 8.04 which resulted in failure. Maybe I should try with older ones? Should I upgrade to latest Ubuntu?
My card is GeForce 8400M GS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looking at nVidia's site, you should have a look at Ubuntu's Add/Remove Programs, and search with nvidia and you will find your driver set. FWIW I use 180.44 on my Dell laptop which has a 8600m GT.

Comment: I installed newest Ubuntu and drivers are there as you said.